# TUI Tool to change directory permission rules?

Tags: permissions, utilities

There are some strangers to Linux who need to use it in terminal mode but they are helplessly limited to accept that using `chmod` and `chown` is dead simple.

They would be satisfied only by a tool that asks them in tui mode to select their target and permission rules. Midnight Commander would be fine if it had recursive mode, as they do not know which file is causing the issue and would like to apply the permission rules per directory.

It wouldn't be hard to make a `dialog` script for this but I'm guessing someone already did it, and would be nice to customize one than to start from scratch.

I'm curious what tool / script do you know of for this?

Comment: One of the problems with having recursive is that it would need to handle the equivalent of `chmod`'s `X` (capital) - most often this is in connection with the fact, that while files are generally not executable, directories generally are.

Comment: Well, there are always terminal based file managers: (e.g., mc and ranger).

Comment: @HalosGhost mc, Midnight Commander I have mentioned in my question, ranger, seems to be dependent on too many things for what I would want with it.

Comment: As far as I know, no one has created an ncurses/dialog utility solely for changing file permissions (since there is rarely a usecase for only that functionality but not other file management; and when there is, the cli utils are plenty fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only TUI based solution that I've found is inside of a file manager called [Last File Manager, aka lfm](https://inigo.katxi.org/devel/lfm/). On F12 there is an option to set permissions and to do it recursively.

Others that I've checked:

- Midnight Commander: There is [a suggestion for midnight commander to have this feature](http://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3109), but as of now, it is still not available.
- Didn't find the feature of chmod/chown-ing recursively in [ranger](https://github.com/ranger/ranger)
- These would be what I was after but they are having a GUI instead of a TUI:

  - https://github.com/IgnorantGuru/permz
  - https://github.com/gitpan/Gtk2-Chmod
  - https://github.com/homebru/permit